# Database tree to java

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

I want to move a tree from database in java.

First I get ResultSet from DB:

```
String selectTree = "select id, id_parent, text from tree ";        
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(selectTree);

resultSet.last();
sizeOfSelect = resultSet.getRow();
resultSet.beforeFirst();

list = new ArrayList<Node>(sizeOfSelect);

while(resultSet.next()) {
    list.add(new Node(resultSet.getInt(1), 
            resultSet.getInt(2), 
            resultSet.getString(3)));
}
```

Now I have an array of nodes:

```
class Node<T> {
    private int id; 
    private int parent_id;
    private String text;

    Node(int _id, int _parentId, String _text) {
        this.id = _id;
        this.parent_id = _parentId;
        this.text = _text;
    }

//getters & setters here
```

How can I obtain the same tree in java?
Could you tell me the line of thought, please.

I have made progress in solution.
I turning array of RawNode in map thus:

```
for(RawNode rawNode : tmpList) {
      tmpMap.put(rawNode.getId(), dependsId(rawNode.getId()));
}
```

Where method dependsId() is:

```
private List<RawNode> dependsId(int id) {
    List<RawNode> tmpDependList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(RawNode rawNode : tmpList) {
        if(rawNode.getParentId() == id) {
            tmpDependList.add(rawNode);
        }
    }
    return tmpList;
}
```

What should I do next? How transform this map in array of Node with parent and children?

Comment: I take that +1 for my last comment as indication ... that your question is by now "answered enough"?! If so - it was nice working with you; but as said: don't expect this to happen every time. In the end, learning programming is **mainly** about doing a lot of things yourself. It seems more convenient and efficient to rely on the experience of other people; but the point is: you *want* to hit the wall ... constantly, until you figure how to solve the puzzle. Having said that, wishing you luck for your future work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, your "raw" Nodes look like this:

```
class RawNode {
  private int id; 
  private int parent_id;
  private String text;
```

[ hint: I renamed that class declaration; and removed the `<T>` part which doesn't make any sense given the fact that you have **nothing** generic in that class; at least from what you showing ]

and ideally, that would mean that there is **exactly** ONE Node object for each ID. In other words; over time, you created objects like:

```
RawNode rootWithoutParent = new Node(0, -1, "root");
RawNode firstChildParent = new Node(1, 0, "root");
```

And you have all these objects in an array/list. Now you could transform those *RawNodes*, into "real" *Nodes*, and that one could look like:

```
class Node {
  private int id; 
  private Node parent;
  private List<Node> children = new ArrayList<>();
  private String text;
```

Translation could be done in multiple iterations.

First, you create one Node per RawNode (and for later, we remember specific information in **two** maps):

```
List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
Map<Node, RawNode> rawNodesByNode = new HashMap<>();
Map<Integer, Node> nodesById = new HashMap<>();
for(RawNode rawNode : tmpList) {
    Node node = new Node();
    node.setId(rawNode.getId());
    node.setText(rawNode.getText());
    rawNodesByNode.put(node, rawNode);
    nodesById.put(rawNode.getId(), node);
}
```

What is missing?

First, the "link" from childs to their parent.

```
for(Node node : nodes) {
  RawNode raw = rawNodesByNode.get(node);
  int parentId = raw.getParentId();
  Node parent = nodesById.get(parentId);
  node.setParent(parent);
}
```

Second ("optional") the "link" from parents to all childs:

```
for(Node node : nodes) {
  Node parent = node.getParent(); // should be != null by now
  parent.addChild(node);
}
```

with:

```
void addChild(Node node) {
  children.add(node);
}
```

( please note: the children list is created directly when you do a Node.new() call; but at that point, it is empty. And beyond that: I didn't put my code into a compiler; it is meant as "pseudo code", to get you going; and give some insights into the required steps. There is also a certain potential for "bugs" - conditions where you need special checking to handle cases like the "root node" which doesn't have a parent; in other words: don't just copy&paste my code: understand what it is *supposed* to do and work from there).

Hope that gives you enough ideas to get you going. And please note: all of this is just "work"; there is no "rocket science" involved; so the essential part is that **you** now engage and **understand** what you are about to do. So resist the urge to ask yet-another question; instead: start **working**.

Comment: Can you read your comment? Hint: you **never** put more than 10 chars of code into a question. And I already told you: this is not a tutor service were we *walk* you through all necessary steps of a solution.

Comment: I see ... you might want to drop me a comment early on tomorrow to remind me to look into your changes ... but as said: have a close look how far you get without me; and then see what exact questions are really blocking your progress.

Comment: Please, look what I got

Comment: I updated my answer; kinda throwing away some of the stuff I spoke about initially. Should be "more complete" by now.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want tree, your Node definitely lacks some links to other nodes(for parent at least), i'd suggest replacing `parent_id` in Node to `Node parentNode`, and set it according to parent_id from database, for example add them all to map at first, mapped by `Map<Integer, Node> someMap`, where integer is id, then when iterate trhough each and do:

```
list.add(new Node(resultSet.getInt(1), 
            someMap.get(resultSet.getInt(2)), 
            resultSet.getString(3)));
```

oh, and don't forget to check if that parent id is not null.

I don't really use result set often, but i suppose it would be better to move them from there to some temporary list.

Really sorry, don't have time to write everything as it should be, but i hope you've got my idea